# Bootstrap CSS not working on Github Pages, but works in localhost

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I'm working on a portfolio and it looks great in localhost, but when I try to commit it to Github (https://gabrielbrickle.github.io/) the CSS does't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/nivo-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/nivo-lightbox-theme/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="color/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It appears that the bootstrap stylesheet is not being applied. I think github requires https. You can just save bootstrap locally and reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use https:// for bootstrap css Link.If you right click , Inspect and look at the Console in Chrome you'd find the errors.

Answer (score 4):

try changing this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

If you open the developer console(right click inspect element), It says youre trying to load from `http` in a `https`

Answer (score 0):

Github is loaded over HTTPS. Referencing external stylesheets will require the same protocol.

You can see the errors in DevTools.

[image: errors]

You can either save Bootstrap locally and reference it, or load it with HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS).

[image: Gabriel Github page with bootstrap]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I messed around and figured out that I had referred to one of the sources incorrectly.  I used the wrong case for the first letter of a folder of a source.  I had used ./Assets/css (incorrect one) instead of ./assets/css (correct one).  Fixing the error fixed the CSS on the Github site as well!